# Css div template

Tags: css, templates, html

My biggest problem in developing web projects is appearance.
Is out there any kind of template divs?
I mean like ready-css boxes with maybe header-content separation which are customizable and beatiful.
I know how to make one of these but i don't have time to do different ones every now and then.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing as websites are always so different, I would recommend the 960 grid system.

It is a template structure that easily  lets you create multi column layouts in any style you want. It takes a bit of getting used to, but in your case, it sounds like it could save a huge amount of time!

http://960.gs/

Answer (score 2):

probably on par with the 960, the Blueprint framework works quite well and saves time.

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

Answer (score 1):

This one is a little more extreme of a CSS framework, but it is a good idea:

http://lesscss.org/

Take a look, its pretty fascinating although i don't think it is that useful.